# jQuery File Upload - how to send a $_POST[""] variable to UploadHandler.php

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, jquery-post

I am using "[jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)" script. When a photo is uploaded, this script works with "UploadHandler.php". My question is, how can I send a post/get variable to UploadHandler.php?

Here is my index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin Basic Plus Demo 1.3.0
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Demo - Basic Plus version</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap3.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">

            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                <input type="hidden" name="albumTom" value="2">
            </span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div id="progress" class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
            <div id="files" class="files"></div>
            <br>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="js/load-image.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="js/bootstrap3.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'localhost/best' ?
                '//localhost/' : 'server/php/',
        uploadButton = $('<button/>')
            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .text('Processing...')
            .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')
                    .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('<br>')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append(file.error);
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
                .text('Upload')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            var link = $('<a>')
                .attr('target', '_blank')
                .prop('href', file.url);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .wrap(link);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            var error = $('<span/>').text(file.error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: ??? https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data (pulled from link in question)

Answer (score 0):

The file server/php/index.php gets the variable and from there you can pass it to the UploadHandler.php class.

Or you can use it directly from the UploadHandler.php file but remember that you have to take it as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it in CodeIgniter, iir you can do the same with require():

```
$params = array("id" => $id, "type" => $type);
$this->load->library('UploadHandler.php', $params);
```

Kevin B's link to the documentation may provide a better means of accomplishing this though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this which is worked for me,

in the index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['passData'] = 'Data';
```

in the Uploadhandler.php

```
$passData = $_SESSION['passData'] ;
```